# Is there nice-looking one-liner to split into variables with type casting?

Tags: python

I use following code:

```
x,y = line.split()
x,y = float(x),float(y)
```

Is there any way to beautify that code into one-line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). As delnan points out in the comment, [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) is also an agreeable choice in this case.

*List comprehension*

```
x,y = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
```

*Generator expression*

```
x,y = (float(x) for x in line.split())
```

*`map`*

```
x,y = map(float, line.split())
```

Comment: Alternatively, `map(float, line.split())`. I'm not a huge `map` fan when you need a `lambda` for it, but in simple cases like this, it reads at least as well.